# Danielsson Function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave, image-segmentation

I am implementing an image segmentation algorithm, at some point I need to implement a function named "Danielsson Function" which 'transforms a binary image into a grayscale distance map in which each particle pixel is assigned a gray-level value equal to its shortest Euclidean distance from the particle border'.
I'm not an expert in image processing and the only way I can imagine is using a BFS algorithm   for every pixel but that would take ages.
I couldn't find much in web, so I want to know is there any optimized way to implement this or is there any Matlab/Octave function that can do such thing?

Comment: this might help http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: What you're trying to do is named [distance transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) and is already part of Octave's image package. See its bwdist function (run `pkg load image; help bwdist`) from the Octave prompt.

Comment: Definitely agree with the distance transform.  Use `bwdist` as Trogdor and carandraug have suggested.

Comment: Thanks @Trogdor you were a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply do that by using the "bwdist" matlab function, as the comments mentioned
and here is the link for help if you needed any : 
   [Distance transform of binary image - MATLAB bwdist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html)
And here is the code :

```
I=uint8(bwdist(some_binary_image))
```

Be sure to use the 'uint8' because 'bwdist' only gives you the distance matrix which has double number values.

Comment: This is really really bad advice! Do NOT use `uint8`, 1) it will truncate distances longer than 255 (very likely to happen); and 2) you'll lose precision and won't be able to distinguish between distances such as 2.5 and 3.4!!! There's a reason it was specified euclidean distance.

Comment: I agree with @carandraug - I don't understand why you're truncating the distances when the shortest Euclidean distance is desired.